# Failure to Revoke ArcGIS Pro Advanced license using Python API

Tags: python, arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, api, arcgis-portal

I am scripting the provisioning and de-provisioning of users for my place of employment. I have the script in place to license users but I am having trouble getting the revoke script to work. I can pull the necessary parts out and run them manually in a python terminal and it still fails to [revoke](https://esri.github.io/arcgis-python-api/apidoc/html/arcgis.gis.admin.html?highlight=revoke#arcgis.gis.admin.License.revoke) the license. When I run it in the terminal the only message I see is "False". When I run it in the script it still fails but apparently not enough to throw an exception. The account that is running this script can provision licenses just fine I have even given the account full administrator access and it still fails. I can log in with the account and de-provision licenses manually but it fails when scripted.

The other issue that I run into is that it won't let me de-provision all of the entitlements at once using this line `if pro_license.revoke(username=user.username, entitlements= '*'):`. I receive this error message `(assign() got an unexpected keyword argument 'supress_email')`

This is the snippet from my script:

```
for user in new_users:
try:
    pro_license = gis.admin.license.get('ArcGIS Pro')
except:
    logger.warning("Cannot query ArcGIS Pro licenses")
    exit(1)

try:
    if pro_license.revoke(username=user.username, entitlements= 'desktopAdvN'):
        logging.info("Removed license from : " + user.username)
        print("Removed license from : " + user.username)
    else:
        logging.warning("Failed to remove license from: " + user.username)
        print("Failed")
except Exception as e:
    logging.warning("Failed to remove license from: " + user.username + "(" + str(e) + ")")`
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chased down the error message that I was receiving `(assign() got an unexpected keyword argument 'supress_email')` turns out somebody made a typo in the _license.py and part of the revoke function was referring to a supress_email variable. I updated my arcgis api and that seems to have fixed it.

I originally edited "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\admin_license.py" to modify the supress_email to suppress_email and that fixed the issue as well.